# React : How to stop re-rendering component or making an API calls on router change for the same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

I need help to stop making same API calls again on route change. I tried to find the solution available on the web and on stackoverflow, but I am not able to figure out what changes require to fix this thing.

I also tried to use sessionStorage to store one flag that if API calls fired then flag set to true and on router change I check if flag is true then don't make any API calls. But then it blanks the list of articles.

I have one main App component with routes, which contains two components : ( Please see below given code )

1. ArticleHome
2. BookmarkHome

the problem which I am facing is, when I first time hits `http://localhost:3001`, it redirects to `http://localhost:3001/articles` page and it renders `ArticleHome` component properly and fetches list of Articles. then I click on Bookmarks link and it renders `http://localhost:3001/bookmarks` route and related component and makes and API call to render bookmark list.

But when I go back to Articles page using router `http://localhost:3001/articles` it again fires API call to fetch articles due to component re-renders on each route change.

Can anyone pleae guide that how can I stop executing API calls again on router change and on component re-render?

Is there any better way to handle API calls on router change for the same component, if data is already loaded?

```
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/articles" />} />
                        <Route path="/articles" render={() => <ArticleHome type="articles" />} />
                        <Route path="/bookmarks" render={() => <BookmarkHome type="bookmarks" />} />
                        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
                    </Switch>
                </React.Fragment>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

In ArticleHome component I have one API call which fetches list of Articles and in 
BookmarkHome component I have another API call which fetches list of Bookmarks.

`ArticleHome` component: ( Same function for `BookmarkHome` component )

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ArticleHome = (props: any) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        articles: [],
        reRender: true
    });

    const [newState, dispatch] = useReducer(articleReducer, state);

    useEffect(() => {


        // componentWillUnmount
        return () => {

            console.log('unmounting 1...');
            setState({
                ...state,
                reRender: false
            });
        }

    },[state.reRender]); // componentDidUpdate

    const fetchAllrecords = () => {
        fetch(url)
        .then((data: any) => {

            dispatch({ type: 'GET_ALL_RECORDS', data: data.docs })

            return data.docs;
        })
    }

return (
    <ul>
        <li>Render article list here</li>
    </ul>
)
}


// Reducer function
// ========================

function articleReducer(state: any, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ALL_RECORDS":
            return {
                ...state,
                articles: action.data,
                reRender: false
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But when I switch to any of the above mentioned components using router it again executes API call.

I have passed `[state.reRender]` in `useEffect` hook to tell react that re-render component only when any new items added or data updates.

In `articleReducer` function I am setting `reRender: false`.

Please let me know if you need further information on this.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Comment: Hello Mr. Raval, is Steve K's answer helpful? I'm having the same problem... After seeing his answer I'm trying to migrate some of the api calls in Context.js

Comment: Hi @LD8, I didn't get chance to try the solution provided by the Steve K.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you solved the problem then?

Comment: yes, I have noticed that useEffect() method helps to stop unnecessary re-render of that component, when used properly as mentioned by Steve

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I would fetch from my api outside of the route components and just pass it down to the route.  Then you don't have to worry about the route change and any programming that would be involved in manipulating the default behavior of the router.  You can do this one of two ways.

**First**
Do your api call higher in the component tree.  So if you would do your api call in the app component then pass it down to the Route you wouldn't have to worry about the rendering of the route.  Your logic would be outside of it.

**Second**
If you don't want a messy app component you could create a context component and do your logic in there.  Then just wrap your components in your context component that you created.  Like so:

Here is a codesandbox [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-rerender-api-fix-8nupf)

Your app component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import First from "./First";
import Second from "./Second";
import Context from "./Context";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Router Rerendering Fix</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">First Route</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/second">Second Route</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Context>
            <Route exact path="/" component={First} />
            <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
          </Context>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Your articles component

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {ApiContext} from "./Context";

const First = () => {
  const context = useContext(ApiContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>First Route</div>
      <ul>
        {context.map((article, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{article}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default First;
```

Your context component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const ApiContext = React.createContext();

const Context = props => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendered');
    setArticles(['Article One', 'Article Two', '...ect'])
  }, []);

  return (
    <ApiContext.Provider value={articles}>
      {props.children}
    </ApiContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Context;
```

Comment: How would you do that if you have multiple components that require different type of data to be fetched from network (say f.e. articles, videos, podcasts, etc.). Do you provide access to all those collections via the Provider to all components even though they only  would f.e. need one data collection? Do you have a code example or a link to an example of how to do that? @Steve K

Comment: @RikvanVelzen this becomes an optimization issue. I really need to know how your app needs to consume this data.  You are not really taking a hit just by passing data to components so if you are going to immediately mount components that will collectively use all of the data then just make one request and fetch all of the data and pass it in the value of the provider.  If not then how are you determining which point of data is needed and adjust your provider information accordingly.  If each component only requires one point of data you can make multiple providers. Whats your app structure?

Comment: @RikvanVelzen Just make one request for each route getting the data you need. There's no performance hit for passing data because you are just referencing a spot in memory. You can pass it all like `value={apiData}` and parse in component or break it up `value={{videos, podcasts, ect}}` it doesn't matter I prefer to break it up.  Wrap each of your routes components in a provider, get data you need here, and consume the data you need in all of the components with a single request. This will also prevent unnecessary re-renders because you already have all of the data you need for the route.